# A complete list of all android devices

Tags: android

I need to map the device model (such as "Samsung GT-I9300") to brand names (such as "Samsung Galaxy S 3"). Where can I find a complete list of devices with a mapping?

**Why I'm asking this:** On Android, `android.os.Build.MODEL` returns the model name, such as GT-I9300. There is no way to get a human-readable brand name, so in order to show a human-readable name, such as "Galaxy S III", I apparently need to manually map all the Android device models in the world. This is why I'm looking for such a list, or a better solution for this issue if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 58):

The only complete list that I can find is: [List of all devices supported by Google Play Store](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB)

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiastic Thank you, I know about MANUFACTURER. It returns "Samsung", but I need "Samsung Galaxy S III".

Comment: @llya // Device model
String PhoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;

android.os.Build.BOARD, 
android.os.Build.BRAND

Comment: Devices are listed in the following format - Marketing Name (Build.os.DEVICE/Build.os.MODEL).
This is very good. THANKS!

Comment: This is a great list, thanks. Does anyone know of a source for this data that is in a table or CSV format so it can be easily imported to a database?

Comment: I had success using Tabula (http://tabula.technology/) to extract the table from the PDF into a CSV.

Comment: There is also a CSV download available: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6154891?hl=en

Comment: Is there anything like this that includes min/max OS support?

Comment: I've merged several sources and shared it on github 
https://github.com/lucbonnin/PhoneModelsConvertor/

Comment: Direct link to the Play Store official list: https://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.html This is easily parseable HTML.